List all of the members' first name, last name and total loan book. Member's First name order by ascending
SELECT 
    MemberFirstName, MemberLastName, COUNT(*) AS TotalBookOnLoan
FROM
    Member
JOIN 
    Loan ON Member.MemberID= Loan.MemberID
WHERE 
    LoanDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    Member.MemberFirstName
ORDER BY 
    MemberFirstName ASC

Why is this query wrong?

How is this query "wrong" ? What is your expectation / desired result - and what do you get instead? Show us input data and the data returned from the query - and please also specify which RDBMS this is for - just "SQL" is too broad a term ...

You need to add more information, just like the other comment suggests. Here is a link that has information on how to wrote a good question on this website: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I see three main flaws in your query:

First, you are aggregating by the first name only, but then selecting both the first and last names.  On most databases, such code would not even run.  And even on databases which might tolerate this syntax (such as MySQL or SQLite), the behavior would probably not be what you want.  The fix is to aggregate by both the first and last name.

You are counting using COUNT(*).  But the problem with this is that members have no books on loan whatsoever would incorrectly show up as having one book on loan.  To fix this, you should count using COUNT(Loan.MemberId).  In the case of a member having no books on loan, this count expression would correctly return zero.

The inner join should be changed to a left join, with the loan date condition being part of the join condition.


Putting all of these fixes in, we can try writing:
SELECT m.MemberFirstName, m.MemberLastName, COUNT(l.MemberID) AS TotalBookOnLoan
FROM Member m
LEFT JOIN Loan l
    ON m.MemberID = l.MemberID AND
       l.LoanDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY m.MemberFirstName, m.MemberLastName
ORDER BY m.MemberLastName, m.MemberFirstName;

